# Anaconda Python kernel dies due to DLL error

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

For a course in machine learning I am doing exercises in python. We are required to use Jupyter Notebook for our assignments. While this works out well on my laptop and on my office desktop, I am not able to run anything on my desktop at home.

Since I am not sure if I am allowed to post the boilerplate code that is given us I will not do so. But it does not appear to be necessary anyway, because the kernel already dies on:

```
import numpy as np
```

The error I am seeing is:

> Die Ordnungszahl 242 wurde in der DLL D:ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\mkl_intel_thread.dll nicht gefunden.

This translates roughly to:

> The atomic number 242 was not found in the DLL [path]\mkl_intel.thread.dll.

The message above comes in a Windows UI context menu window. Jupyter which is running in the browser gives me a more generalized error shortly after:

> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

Since I am now bedridden for a week and my laptop is in the office, I would like to work on the current assignment, however I don't see what may cause this error.

My machine runs an Intel i5, an nVidia GPU and 24GB RAM, OS is Windows 10 64Bit. There are already IDEs on the system, with C++ projects and Java projects, namely there are:

- Visual Studio Code
- CLion
- IDEA
- Visual Studio
- Eclipse

There was also a Python 3.5 distribution on the system, however I removed it after first installing Jupyter Notebook and running into the error.

Overall I reinstalled Jupyter three times now, rebooting each time. I also redownloaded it everytime, to prevent having selected the wrong Bit version and to prevent corrupted downloads.

Right now I don't know where this comes from. Does someone have experience with this issue?

Comment: Did you reinstall Jupyter or the whole anaconda distribution?

Comment: So after you removed the python 3.5 you did reinstall all your packages via anaconda navigator or something comparable? Or are you trying to use the old libraries with a new python kernel?

Comment: I first installed Anaconda fully, while having the original Python distribution still on my system. Got the error. Removed the Python distribution, leaving Anaconda. Got the error. Removed Anaconda with all of its packages and reinstalled. Got the error. Removed and redownloaded Anaconda to be safe with respect to Bit version and did a full installation again. Got the error. This is where I am at.

Comment: So how did you install the packages? Is it possible you used outdated channels? Or maybe even an outdated package manager? Your error sounds like something that might happen if you use an python 3.5 package in an 3.7 environment.

Comment: By using the official Anaconda installer.

Comment: https://www.anaconda.com/download/

It comes with its own Python distribution.

Comment: I too think, that this appears like something, where Python distributions collide, because some simple calls do work. However having installed Anaconda exactly the same way on the other machines, I fail to see what is breaking and why.